# Python Click: NoSuchOption exception when manually attaching Option objects to Command instance using

Tags: python, command-line-interface, python-click

My code sample:

```py
import click


def std_cb(ctx, param, standardize):
    if standardize:
        opt = click.Option(param_decls=['-a'],
                           help='this option only exists when -S is set')
    else:
        opt = click.Option(param_decls=['-b'],
                           help='this option only exists when -S is not set')
    ctx.command.params.append(opt)
    return standardize


@click.command()
@click.option('-S', '--standardize/--no-standardize', is_eager=True,
              is_flag=True, default=False, callback=std_cb)
def get_options(standardize, **extra_opts):
    print(locals())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    uis = get_options.main(standalone_mode=False)
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to be able to dynamically create different options for a given command depending on the value of an eager flag option to the same command using the click library.

When I execute the above command on the CLI as `$ python cli_test.py`, this is printed to stdout `{'standardize': False, 'extra_opts': {}}`, as expected. Similarly `$ python cli_test.py -S` prints `{'standardize': True, 'extra_opts': {}}`, also expected.

And when I invoke the built-in `--help` option with `$ python cli_test.py --help`, I get:

```sh
Usage: cli_test.py [OPTIONS]

Options:
  -S, --standardize / --no-standardize
  -b TEXT                         this option only exists when -S is not set
  --help                          Show this message and exit.
```

Which seems to suggest that the attachment of the `--no-standardize` specific option via the `std_cb` callback for the `-S` flag is working as well.

Similarly, `$ python cli_test.py --help -S`, produces:

```sh
Usage: cli_test.py [OPTIONS]

Options:
  -S, --standardize / --no-standardize
  -a TEXT                         this option only exists when -S is set
  --help                          Show this message and exit.
```

Now with the `-a` option appearing due to the presence of the `-S` flag.

However, if I were to try and do `$ python cli_test.py -b hello`, I'd get the error: `click.exceptions.NoSuchOption: no such option: -b`.

And similarly, `$ python cli_test.py -S -a world` produces `click.exceptions.NoSuchOption: no such option: -a`, despite them showing up in the help page under their applicable `-S` flag value.

What I had expected to see from the given code example is of course, `$ python cli_test.py -b hello` printing `{'standardize': True, 'extra_opts': {'b': 'hello'}}`.

And `$ python cli_test.py -S -a world` printing `{'standardize': True, 'extra_opts': {'a': 'world'}}`.

In the [Click docs](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/api/#click.option), the authors do state that using `@click.option` "is equivalent to creating an Option instance manually and attaching it to the `Command.params` list.", so I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if your code should work, but I wonder if you could live with something like I've sketched here:

```
import click


def require_standardize_set(ctx, param, value):                                                                                                                   
    if value and not ctx.params['standardize']:
        raise click.UsageError('-{} requires that -S is set'.format(param.name))
    return value

def require_standardize_not_set(ctx, param, value):
    if value and ctx.params['standardize']:
        raise click.UsageError('-{} requires that -S is not set'.format(param.name))
    return value


@click.command()
@click.option('-S', '--standardize/--no-standardize',
              is_flag=True, default=False, is_eager=True)
@click.option('-a', help='this option requires that -S is set',
              callback=require_standardize_set)
@click.option('-b', help='this option requires that -S is not set',
              callback=require_standardize_not_set)
def get_options(standardize, **extra_opts):
    print(locals())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    uis = get_options.main(standalone_mode=False)
```

This seems to me to produce the same results (except `extra_opts` always includes both `a` and `b`, but with the values of `None` if not set). A benefit, from my point of view is that the documentation always documents both `a` and `b`. As a user, I assume I would want that.

Comment: This is something that I'd considered as well. However it doesn't quite do what I want, as another application I'd like to have is to be able to dynamically set different default values for a set of shared options based on the value of the eager flag. Thanks for the try anyway, gave you an upvote.